# Could not find gem 'pg (= 0.12.4) ruby' in any of the gem sources listed in your Gemfile or available on this machine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, gemfile

I'm trying to run the following for on my Kali box, see error.

```
root@kali:~# ruby /usr/share/metasploit-framework/tools/nasm_shell.rb
Could not find rake-10.4.2 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

I then run bundle install and get the below error:

```
Could not find gem 'pg (= 0.12.4) ruby' in any of the gem sources listed in your Gemfile or available on this machine.
```

The errors just keep on! Ive installed RVM since that was also an issue. Ive ran bundle update, no luck. ect..

my Gemfile is as follows:

```
 require 'pathname'

# During build, the Gemfile is temporarily moved and
# we must manually define the project root
if ENV['MSP_ROOT']
  root = Pathname.new(ENV['MSP_ROOT'])
else
  root = Pathname.new(__FILE__).parent
end
metamodules_load_path = root.join('metamodules', 'lib').expand_path.to_path

unless $LOAD_PATH.include? metamodules_load_path
  $LOAD_PATH.unshift metamodules_load_path
end

require 'metasploit/pro/metamodules'

source 'https://rubygems.org'

# All gems are listed alphabetically within their own group or sections.  When adding a gem please add a comment above
# the declaration explaining why the gem was added.

#
# Root
#

gemspec path: 'ui'
gemspec path: 'engine'
gemspec name: 'metasploit-framework-full', path: 'msf3'

Metasploit::Pro::Metamodules.gemspecs(self)

# We purchase and use RailsLTS which is slipstreamed into our build process.
# RailsLTS requires this publically available gem.
# Please note, installing this gem on its own does not install RailsLTS.
gem 'railslts-version', '>= 3.2.21'

# CSS helpers
gem 'compass'
# Make white listed rails routes available in javasript
gem 'js-routes'
# Delayed jobs on linux needs daemons
gem 'daemons', :platforms => :ruby
# Used to pass static data to javasript from Ruby
gem 'gon'
# Jbuilder for Builder-eque JSON templates
gem 'jbuilder'
# Javascript framework for the UI
gem 'jquery-rails', '~> 3.1.1'
# Pagination
gem 'kaminari', '~> 0.14.0'
# Metasploit credential models
gem 'metasploit-credential', '~> 0.14.5'


# Mdm models
gem 'metasploit_data_models', '~> 0.24.0'
# MIME type identification for files
gem 'mime-types', '1.18', :git => 'git://github.com/rapid7/mime-types.git'
# Adds to Rails 3 deprecated prototype JS helpers from Rails 2
gem 'prototype_legacy_helper', '0.0.0', :git => 'git://github.com/jvennix-r7/prototype_legacy_helper.git'
# RestClient needed for nexpose vuln verification
gem 'rest-client', '~> 1.6.7'
# parses robot.txt files for thin
gem 'robots', '0.10.1'
# TODO: REMOVE RSPEC!!!!!
# See https://jira.tor.rapid7.com/browse/MSP-10788
gem 'rspec'
# webserver
gem 'thin'
# treetop is needed by the mail gem, but for some reason isn't properly
# included when omitting development and test bundler groups
gem 'treetop'

#
# pcap group from metasploit-framework
#

# PCAPRUB
gem 'pcaprub', :git => 'git://github.com/bturner-r7/pcaprub.git', :branch => 'rapid7'
# Secure web headers and XSS defense-in-depth
gem 'secure_headers'


#
# Extension gems.
#

# JSON parsing
gem 'json'
# RPC library for API calls in controllers
gem 'msgpack'
# Parses HTML for webpage cloner
gem 'nokogiri'
# arel-helpers: Useful tools to help construct database queries with ActiveRecord and Arel.
gem 'arel-helpers'

#
# Windows-only gems used by prosvc.  All are extension gems, so they must be have fixed version to match pre-compiled
# gems.
#

# Dependency of windows-api
# version pinned to pre-installed version in ruby/lib
gem 'win32-api', '1.5.2', :platform => 'mingw'
# Allow thin to run as a Windows service in thin_service_install.rb
# version pinned to pre-installed version in ruby/lib
gem 'win32-service', '0.7.2', :platform => 'mingw'
# Dependency of windows-pr
# version pinned to pre-installed version in ruby/lib
gem 'windows-api', '0.4.3', :platform => 'mingw'
# Allows using windows calls as methods instead of as procs
# version pinned to pre-installed version in ruby/lib
gem 'windows-pr', '1.2.4', :platform => 'mingw'

#
# Groups - listed alphabetically
#

group :assets do
  # CoffeeScript integration in rails
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.2'
  # We have compile errors with >=1.5.  These can probably be fixed and this line removed.
  gem 'coffee-script-source', '< 1.5'
  # Compass CSS library in rails
  gem 'compass-rails', '1.0.1'
  # Coffeescript client-side templates
  gem 'eco', '1.0.0'
  # CoffeeScript to JavaScript conversion
  gem 'execjs', '1.3.0'
  # Handlebars integration in rails
  gem 'handlebars_assets'
  gem 'hamlbars', '~> 2.0.1'
  # Sass integration in rails
  gem 'sass-rails', '~> 3.2.4'
  # JavaScript virtual machine for execjs
  gem 'therubyracer'
  # JavaScript minification
  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

# DO NOT add debuggers or other debugging gems to the Gemfile.  The various debuggers will interfere with each other.
# gem 'debugger' specifically interferes with the 'ruby-debug-ide' gem installed by Rubymine.  As a courtesy to other
# developers using different debuggers, install and require your debuggers as needed using plain gem install and
# manually requiring the debugger file OR modify the Gemfile, but DO NOT commit the change.
group :development do
  # replaces standard error page with interactive stack and REPL in each stack frame.
  gem 'better_errors', '~> 0.9.0'
  # enables REPL and local/instance variable inspection for better_errors
  gem 'binding_of_caller'
  # static analysis security scanner for Rails.  Used on Jenkins.
  gem 'brakeman'
  # configuration tweaks for Rails 3.1+
  gem 'rails-dev-tweaks', '~> 0.6.1'
  # markdown formatting for yard
  gem 'redcarpet'
  # generate API documentation
  gem 'yard'
  gem "yard-cucumber"
  gem 'yard-restful', '~> 1.2.3'
  gem "rails-erd", :git => "git://github.com/lsanchez-r7/rails-erd.git"
  gem 'pry'
end

group :development, :test do
  # automatically load factories
  gem 'factory_girl_rails'
  # Needs to be in development as well as test so that `rake spec` works.
  gem 'rspec-rails', '2.14.2'
  # teaspoon is a javascript test runner for Rails
  gem "teaspoon"
  # Adding in awesome_print for better console output
  # colorizes and formats rails console, it can be added to your ~/.irbrc
  # require "awesome_print"; AwesomePrint.irb!.
  gem 'awesome_print'
  # Foreman to manage all the process we are starting to use
  gem 'foreman'
  # Using faker for development and testing of the nexpose integration
  gem 'faker'
  gem 'parallel_tests'
end

group :test do
  # Rails integrations for cucumber
  gem 'cucumber-rails', :require => false
  # this displayes the currently running step.
  gem 'slowhandcuke'

  gem 'capybara', '~> 2.2.1'
  gem 'capybara-firebug', '~> 2.0.0'
  gem 'capybara-json', '~> 0.3.0'
  gem 'ci_reporter'
  gem 'database_cleaner', '~> 0.8.0'
  gem 'fivemat'
  gem 'headless'
  gem 'msgpack-rpc', '~> 0.5.2'
  gem 'rbvmomi', :git => 'git://github.com/rapid7/rbvmomi.git', :branch => 'patches-1.8.1'
  gem 'rspec_junit_formatter'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver', '~> 2.44'
  # add matchers from shoulda, such as validates_presence_of, which are useful for testing validations
  gem 'shoulda-matchers'
  gem 'simplecov', :github => "colszowka/simplecov", :ref => "88a649aec0", :require => false
  gem 'simplecov-rcov'
  gem 'timecop', '~> 0.7'
  gem 'spork'
  gem 'webrat'
end
```

Please let me know how to resolve this issue!?

Answer (score 33):

You need to install `libpq-dev` first

```
sudo apt-get install libpq-dev
```

Then you can install `gem pg` via terminal

```
gem install pg
```

OR adding in `Gemfile`, you can add version if have any dependency

```
gem 'pg'
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `gemfile` does not seem to reference the `pg` gem directly. But the problem you are facing is that the repository [https://rubygems.org](https://rubygems.org/gems/pg/versions) does not have the `pg` gem version 0.12.4.

you can try adding a version that is present there

```
gem 'pg', '~> 0.12.2'
```

or a more recent version like '0.18.3' or '0.13.2'.

Answer (score 0):

Need to update your Gemfile to include the following line

> source 'https://rubygems.org'

Ex : Gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
group :development do
  gem 'capistrano'
  gem 'capistrano-ssh-doctor'
  gem 'capistrano-bundler'
  gem 'capistrano-passenger', '>= 0.1.1'
end
```